# getting the minimum for arrays and for statments?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I sorta  need help getting the minimum I keep getting thirteen can some
one help me out? The issue I believe is I'm not showing the formula for low n line  I'm confused I have tried to switch out the values for the array and I can't figure it out just if someone could explain to m please.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int getHighest(int numArray[], int numElements);
int getLowest(int numArray[], int numelements);

int main()
{
    int numbers[4] = { 13, 2, 40, 25 };

    cout << "The highest number in the array is " << getHighest(numbers, 4) << "." << endl;
    cout << "The lowest number in the array is "<< getLowest(numbers,0) << "." << endl;
    return 0;
}
int getHighest(int numArray[], int numElements)
{
    int high = numArray[0];

    for (int sub = 1; sub < numElements; sub += 1)
        if (numArray[sub] > high)
            high = numArray[sub];
       
    return high;
}
int getLowest(int numArray[], int numElements)
{
    int low = numArray[0];
    for (int sub = 0; sub >= numElements; sub--)
        if (numArray[sub]< low)
            low = numArray[sub];
    return low;
}
```

Comment: `for(int sub=0; sub >= numElements; sub--)` What would `sub` be in each iteration? with `numElements` being `0` your for loop only runs once. Hence, the output 13.

Comment: Yet another bug: `getLowest(numbers,0)`. The 2nd parameter provides the number of elements (of the array in the 1st parameter). That's in your case `4` as you did in `getHighest(numbers, 4)`.

Comment: hey Chester that's the part I'm confused about i get what your saying just don't fully understand?

Comment: If you use `sub--` you DEcrement your loop index. (`sub--` could be written as `sub -= 1` or `sub = sub - 1` as well.) Hence, you have to start with the highest possible index, and you have to check whether index is still `>= 0` in the loop condition. Sloppy spoken, you go backwards through your array. So, you have to start at the end of it.

Comment: Btw. if you have a decrementing loop then be careful with the start index. If an array has _n_ elements the last element has index _n - 1_.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat can you break down what your were trying to say in the last statement? im dumb sorrry for not understanding? you gusy are awesome thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the corrected example:

```
int getLowest(int numArray[], int numElements)
{
    int low = numArray[0];
    for (int sub = 1; sub < numElements; ++sub)
        {
        //std::cout<<"checking: "<<numArray[sub]<<"with"<<low<<std::endl;
        if (numArray[sub]< low){
            low = numArray[sub];
        }
            
        }
    return low;
}
```

The complete working example is [here](https://onlinegdb.com/WcdSLGVqR)

Also note in your given example **you have made a mistake** at:

```
cout << "The lowest number in the array is "<< getLowest(numbers,0) << "." << endl;
```

Instead of passing 0 as the second argument you should pass 4 as i did [here](https://onlinegdb.com/WcdSLGVqR).

**Another mistake** was the initial value of varaible `sub` in the for loop. You started with `sub = 0` instead of `sub = numelements - 1`.
That is the `for` loop should have looked like:

```
//note in the next line we have sub >=1 instead of sub>=0 becuase you have already stored numArray[0] in variable low
for (int sub = numElements -1; sub >=1; --sub)
{
    ...other code here
}
```

Comment: @anoop Rana thank you that makes sense why did you put the ++ before the sub in that ling you corrected? thank you again for your help.

Comment: @ColtonGil The `++` in `++i` is called pre-increment operator. A pre-increment operator is used to increment the value of a variable by 1. So for example if we have `int x = 10;` and then we write `++x;` this means value of variable `x` will be incremented by 1. You can read more about it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec) . You can also use `sub +=1`  in the for loop instead of `++sub`. The result will be same.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning `getLowest()`:

There is actually no need to iterate backwards. It could be done like in `getHighest()`. However, say this is a requirement for teaching…

The test array is

```
int numbers[4] = { 13, 2, 40, 25 };
// indices:        0   1  2   3
// number of elements: 4
```

A loop to iterate backwards has to start with index `numElements - 1` (`3` in this case) and to stop at index `0`.

```
for (int sub = numElements - 1; sub >= 0; sub--)
```

Nevertheless, this will check the last element which is already assigned before the loop. (`getHighest()` starts the loop with the 2<sup>nd</sup> element for this reason: `for (int sub = 1;`…) Thus, this can be corrected to:

```
for (int sub = numElements - 2; sub >= 0; sub--)
```